# Does a linear isomorphism $f: V\to V$ automatically yield the direct sum decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Let $f: V\to V$ be linear map and an isomorphism. Does this condition automatically yield a direct sum in the form of

$$V = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{Im}( T)$$

I am working on a problem right now where $f$ is not a given isomorphism, but I've managed to reduce $f$ to an isomorphism. I am not sure if this immediately implies Rank-Nullity (other than a dimension argument).

> The map is \begin{align} f^2 = f. \end{align} But I just want to know technique.

Comment: If $f$ is an isomorphism, is not $ker(f)=\{0\}?$

Comment: Yes it is, that how I deduced it and hence $\dim V = 1+ \dim Im f$. But does this yield an decomposition like I desire?

Comment: @Hawk $\dim \{0\}=0$.

Comment: Right sorry 10 char